# Simple question about Riemann zeta function

Tags: analysis

So, we have

$ \zeta(s) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s} $

We know that it converges for all $s$ with real part bigger than $1$.

My question is: how is defined hear $ \frac{1}{n^s}$. For example, if $s=1/3$, what third root of $n$ do we take when we write 
$ \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{3}}} $ ?

I know that  $ n^s = \exp ^  {s \log(n)} $, but what branch of log do we take?

Comment: But the real part of $\;s=\frac13\;$ is **not** bigger than $\;1\;$ ...!

Comment: Yeah I know. But the question is the same for the numbers with real part bigger than 1. It was to semplify, it's the same for example woth $ s = 3/2$

Comment: Then I guess that it is meant that in any case a real root must be taken and, if more than one option exists, the positive one, meaning: the principal value for even roots, like $\;1/2 , 1/4, 1/16, ...\;$\ etc., and for odd ones we have no problem, say: $\;8^{1/3}=2\;$ and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the theory of Dirichlet series we always mean $\exp(- s \ln n)$ for $n^{-s}$.

You can replace $\ln n$ by $l_n=\log n$ for some branch of $\log$, the point is to choose it in such a way that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp(- s l_n)$ converges and is analytic for $s \in U \supset (1,\infty)$ and such that $l_m + l_n = l_{mn}$ so that the Euler product $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp(- s l_n) = \prod_p \frac{1}{1-\exp(- s l_p)}$ stays true, but only the choice $l_n = \ln n$ leads to the theory of Dirichlet series.

If not choosing $l_n = \ln n$ then $l_m + l_n = l_{mn}$ will make $\Im (l_n)$ very complicated (*) and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp(- s l_n)$ will loose most of its nice properties.

(*) try with $l_p = \ln p + 2i\pi$ then $l_n = \ln n + 2i\pi \Omega(n)$